# Post to PHP backend from javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I have tried other answers but none have worked. The javascript code is supposed to submit a list of product id's to a php page. When products are selected, the submit button triggers the submit function.

```
       function submit() {
            var ids = bundle.map(function(item){
                $('#product-'+item.id+' button').attr('disabled', false);
                return item.id;
                 });
            console.log(ids);
            //send the ids to api
              bundle = [];
            $('.bundle-list').empty();
            $('.total').html('No item in bundle');
            $('.submit').addClass('hide');
        }
```

I have tried inserting this line in the function

```
document.getElementByID("test").value = bundle;
```

and a hidden tag within the form but can't get the var to submit to PHP

```
<input type="hidden" id="test" name="test" visibility="hidden"></input>
```

Where should the position of the hidden element be relative to the JS code? and any other methods of retrieving the ID's?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in here that sends data. You should have a `$.ajax` or `$.post` or something to do so.

Comment: @RobertAKARobin Please show how that would fit into the function above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either by $.post or $.get variable you can send data to PHP file, but i think you want to save pids in hidden field, but you are not update its value on submit. like

```
$('#test').html('YOUR DATA')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
function submit() {
var ids = bundle.map(function(item){
          $('#product-'+item.id+' button').attr('disabled', false);
           return item.id;
          });
 $.ajax({
    url: 'YOUR_URL HERE',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { qry: ids },
    success: function(data) {
         ///WHEN SUCCESS
        }
    },
    error: function(e) {

    }
 });
}
```